# Is it possible to prevent Trim() from removing a space?

Tags: c#, string, trim

This might seem like an odd question, but is there any way of putting space in a string in such a way that `Trim()` will not remove it?

e.g. I want the output to be, for example, `"Hello, World   "` (this is how I want it to be displayed).

The obvious answer is, don't call `Trim()`, unfortunately in this case I am passing the string into a library (to which I don't have the source code) and that library is doing the trimming.

Maybe there's a character that looks like a space but isn't really and so won't be trimmed? Or some invisible character to put at the end of the string?

Comment: `Trim (params char[] trimChars);`  you can pass `trimChars` the chars that you want to be trimmed

Comment: Because you don't have the hand on the lib. Here is my hacky solution: you could replace the space by another special character (like |) which won't be trimmed when calling the lib. Then re replace your char to space...

Comment: I was thinking the same as @WilliamW. You can replace the spaces in the original string with your character and when you receive the string back from the library, replace the character with space.

Comment: Do you still need your magic character to be processes *as a space* by that library? Or is that library only a gateway, and you either control both sides of it or a magic character would be fine? What I mean is, does the library form a gateway around an api, for instance, that wouldn't accept this kind of magic character?

Comment: @styx - as I said the `Trim()` is in a library so I can't modify the source code.

Comment: @WilliamW - unfortunately the library also displays the string so I can't modify the string after the `Trim()`

Comment: Hmm... an answer was posted which worked but it has been deleted (I was waiting to accept!)

Comment: Yeah my idea didnt work, Trim seems to pick them all up

Comment: You'll have to append a non-printing character, like "\u200b".

Comment: @MichaelRandall  guess if it worked (as the OP asserts), it's because the library is not actually using `Trim()` to trim whitespace, but an overload that specifies the characters to remove (or a different method altogether).

Comment: Hmmm... it worked for me, I suppose I just assumed it was using `Trim()` because that is the effect!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a different write space, it may or may not work for you

```
var str = "test    ";
var str2 = str.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
```

Any of these really

```
U+00A0  NO-BREAK SPACE  
U+1680  OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+180E  MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
U+2000  EN QUAD 
U+2001  EM QUAD 
U+2002  EN SPACE (nut)  
U+2003  EM SPACE (mutton)   
U+2004  THREE-PER-EM SPACE (thick space)    
U+2005  FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (mid space)   
U+2006  SIX-PER-EM SPACE    
U+2007  FIGURE SPACE    
U+2008  PUNCTUATION SPACE   
U+2009  THIN SPACE  
U+200A  HAIR SPACE  
U+200B  ZERO WIDTH SPACE    
U+202F  NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE   
U+205F  MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000  IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE   
U+FEFF  ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `Trim()` will consider as whitespace everything defined as whitespace in Unicode specification. Just checked your sample - `Trim()` removes \u00A0 as well as regular space.

Comment: @Dennis The OP has already confirmed that this works. This must be because the library they mention is NOT calling `Trim()` but is using some other method (e.g. `Trim(char[])`).

Comment: Accepting this because not only did it work with my library, but I had call to actually use Trim() myself (outside the library) on the same string and it didn't remove the space at the end! The character used was the Zero Width No-Break Space (U+FEFF)